# Updating a class attribute through a callback

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, events, callback

I'm building a application that needs to load different settings based on the active window/program (ex. if you're using chrome, the settings associates with Chrome are loaded, when you switch to MS Word, the MS Word settings are loaded).

Right now I'm working on a class that fetches the correct settings from a database every time the active window changes. This class will also have a "LookUp" method that returns a value based on the settings last fetched.

To describe what I'm trying to implement in pseudo code:

```
class RecipeBook{
   public:
       RecipeBook();
       HWINEVENTEVENTHOOK hEvent;
       string currentProgram;
       static VOID CALLBACK WindowCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, 
                                           DWORD dwEvent,
                                           HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, 
                                           LONG idChild, 
                                           DWORD dwEventThread, 
                                           DWORD dwmsEventTime); //Actual callback
       void messageCheck(void*);
 }

 RecipeBook::RecipeBook(){
      this->hEvent = SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 
                                     EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, 
                                     NULL,&WinEventProcCallback, 
                                     0, 0, 
                                     WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT | WINEVENT_SKIPOWNPROCESS);

      Start messageCheck(void*) in separate thread
 }

 void messageCheck(void*){
    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0))
    {
     TranslateMessage(&msg);
     DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

 }

 VOID CALLBACK WindowCallback(HWINEVENTHOOK hWinEventHook, 
                                           DWORD dwEvent,
                                           HWND hwnd, LONG idObject, 
                                           LONG idChild, 
                                           DWORD dwEventThread, 
                                           DWORD dwmsEventTime){

       Get the name of the active program from the HWND handle //This is working
       Update RecipeBook->CurrentProgram
 }
```

The problems I'm having with this:

1) Can't get the message checking to run in a separate thread. If I run the code sequentially it works fine. When I try to spawn messageCheck in a thread (using

```
    AfxBeginThread(&messageCheck, &currentProgram, THREAD_PRIORITY_NORMAL, 0, 0,NULL)
```

)

it just doesn't seem like the other thread is created.

2) I don't know how to modify the values in RecipeBook from the callback. I've thought of returning the name from the callback but I haven't managed to get that to work. It would be nice if I could just edit the string from within the callback.

3) I thought of just asking for the current active program whenever the LookUp method was called but I was only able to find methods that get the calling process ID, not the active windows process ID.

It's a big question but any advice would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: My first thought is that AfxBeginThread requires the thread function to match a particular signature:

UINT __cdecl MyControllingFunction( LPVOID pParam );

You should be able to check the return value of the AfxBeginThread call to see if there's a parameter error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
GetForgroundWindow()
```

That is what I was looking for!

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633505(v=vs.85).aspx

For some reason I was trying to use GetActiveWindow() and whenever I saw Forground window for some reason I was thinking background windows. Ooops!

Unless anyone can provide a good explanation how to do the multitasking, CALLBACK stuff, I'm going to just use this function and query the current window whenever a LookUp is done. Shouldn't be that often and this process won't take too long.

For anyone interested in how you get the name of the process from the active window/the PID using the window handle, this is how I've been doing it:

```
DWORD processID;
LPTSTR processName = new TCHAR[MAX_PATH];
DWORD nameSize = MAX_PATH;
HWND activeWindowH = GetForegroundWindow();
DWORD threadID = GetWindowThreadProcessId(activeWindowH,&processID);
HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_LIMITED_INFORMATION | PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION,FALSE,processID);
BOOL nameSuccess = QueryFullProcessImageName(processHandle,0,processName,&nameSize);
```

Cheers!